# Where does jboss eap 6.x deploy the war file?

Tags: jboss, jboss-eap-6

I used the jboss web console http://xxxxx:9990/console/App.html#deployments to successfully deploy my web app. And I can visit the page in this app.

But I can not find my war file under **jboss-eap-6.2/standalone/deployments.**
Where does jboss backend put the war file?

thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Under the base directory of your jboss instance will be `/data` and `/tmp` folders corresponding to `${jboss.server.data.dir}` and `${jboss.server.tmp.dir}`. These folders are created by jboss when it first starts.

The uploaded war is stored in a file called `/data/content/ad/xxxxx/content` where xxxxx is some temporary directory name.

When JBoss is running the exploded contents of your war will be in the `/tmp/vfs/temp/tempxxxxxxx/content-yyyyyyy` where xxxxxxx and yyyyyyy are random hex values.

These files are all internal to JBoss. When JBoss is stopped you can safely remove the `/tmp` folder and on the next startup JBoss will redeploy the war from the uploaded `/data` file contents - this is controlled by an entry in your `configuration.xml` file.

If you accidentally remove the `/data` folder then JBoss will not start. To fix this you need to either start your instance with the `--admin-only` switch and redeploy your war, or carefully edit your `configuration.xml` to remove the deployment, and then start JBoss and redeploy your war using the console.

Comment: Is the jboss-eap-6.2/standalone/deployments still used? If so, what is the difference between the two?

Comment: The /standalone/deployments folder provides another way to deploy an application by physically placing the file(s) to be deployed in there. JBoss scans the folder and tries to deploy the application. The original question was about deploying using the web console and where JBoss places the uploaded file(s) in its internal structure.

Comment: When I used the jboss as maven plugin, it deployed to /data/content... also and not standalone/deployment. If I copied a jar into standalone/deployment while the server was running , it did not deploy it but wildfly server did

Comment: Yes maven is yet another method of deploying an app.  If you copy an app package to JBoss /standalone/deployments you also need to add a "flag" file with the name of the app suffixed with .dodeploy. It depends on the configured scan settings and is not related to the question to that the OP asked which was specifically about web console deployments.